# azcopy sync scanns 0 files at source

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azure-storage-account, azcopy

I am trying to sync two Azure blob storage containers with the azcopy CLI on a linux machine. The service principal used has the 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role. Furthermore, there is a directory containing csv files in source container `https://sourcestoragetest103.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer`.

The destination container `https://destinationstoragetest103.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer` is empty.

The bash script used looks like this:

```
azcopy login --tenant-id $AZCOPY_TENANT_ID --service-principal --application-id $AZCOPY_SPA_APPLICATION_ID

azcopy sync https://sourcestoragetest103.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer https://destinationstoragetest103.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer --recursive=true --delete-destination=true --check-md5
```

Run output:

```
INFO: If you set an environment variable by using the command line, that variable will be readable in your command line history. Consider clearing variables that contain credentials from your command line history.  To keep variables from appearing in your history, you can use a script to prompt the user for their credentials, and to set the environment variable.
INFO: SPN Auth via secret succeeded.
INFO: SPN Auth via secret succeeded.
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Authenticating to source using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job 59fac848-bde6-864a-4c9c-c96ad46711c9 has started
Log file is located at: /home/userme/.azcopy/59fac848-bde6-864a-4c9c-c96ad46711c9.log

100.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0

Job 59fac848-bde6-864a-4c9c-c96ad46711c9 Summary
Files Scanned at Source: 0
Files Scanned at Destination: 0
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0334
Number of Copy Transfers for Files: 0
Number of Copy Transfers for Folder Properties: 0 
Total Number Of Copy Transfers: 0
Number of Copy Transfers Completed: 0
Number of Copy Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Deletions at Destination: 0
Total Number of Bytes Transferred: 0
Total Number of Bytes Enumerated: 0
Final Job Status: Completed
```

The azcopy binary can't find the directories and files in the source directory.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

```
Files Scanned at Source:  0  
Files Scanned at Destination:  0  
Number of Copy Transfers for Files:  0
```

> Note: As per your error, **azcopy sync** command is not able to find any files to sync from the source container to the destination container.

To verify that there are files in your source container, you can run the below command:

```
 sudo azcopy list https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/kamalifile
```

**Output:**

[image]

I have followed below steps to copy the files from one container to another container in **Linux VM**.

1. Created an application and assigned role to storage account.
2. Once create the application logged in with service prinicipal using below commands.

   ```
   sudo azcopy login --tenant-id $AZCOPY_TENANT_ID --service-principal --application-id $AZCOPY_SPA_APPLICATION_ID 

   sudo azcopy sync "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/kamalifile<sastoken>" "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/myfile<sastoken>" --recursive=true --delete-destination=true
   ```

**Output:**

[image]

Once ran the above commands files are copied to another container in portal.

[image]